# Should I open a new window with a new webdriver or use one webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I need to use two websites at the same time, so I create two web drivers and open a window for each one. Is it a better idea to just create one web driver and then open a new tab and switch between the tabs and why? I am using Selenium.

Comment: depends on your requirements.  If you really need two actions happening at the same time, then you need two threads, one for each driver/browser pair.  If, instead, you have a specific sequence it'll be easier to just use one driver/browser.  (You won't have to manage the threads and the timing of them...)  What is it that you are testing here?  (concurrency at the DB side?)

Comment: i login to one website end perform an action like creating a new group, then i log into a different admin website and approve it. then i go back to the first website and perform another action

Comment: I think it's a toss up.  I'd try it with one driver and see how it goes.  You'd have to login/logout a couple times.  If there's domain based logins things may get tricky.  You might even want two driver and machines, or one driver in a virtual machine.  Probably a better test case that way too.  Depends on what sort of indication there is that something requires approval.